# Old Embedded Jetty Code (SSL) no longer working

Tags: jetty

Had this sample for a few years and it worked fine.
Attempted to use it again and it now returns a Protocol Error.

Not familiar enough with this API to know if anything has changed which is why this sample was copied a while back. Searched again and found another sample with similar code but that too returned the same error which leads me to believe there is possibly a new requirement with this API.

```
> cat EmbeddedJettyHTTPS.java
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

public class EmbeddedJettyHTTPS
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Server server = new Server();
       server.setHandler ( new HelloServlet());
       ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
       connector.setPort(9999);

        HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
        https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory("/myDirecotry/mykeystore");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("myPassword");

        ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
                        new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
                        new HttpConnectionFactory(https));
        sslConnector.setPort(8443);
        sslConnector.setIdleTimeout(50000);

        server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{ sslConnector });

        server.start();
        server.join();

    }

    public static class HelloServlet extends AbstractHandler
    {
            @Override
        public void handle( String target,
                        Request baseRequest,
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException,
                                                      ServletException
            {
            // Declare response encoding and types
                response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");

                // Declare response status code
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

                // Write back response
                response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");

            // Inform jetty that this request has now been handled
                baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        }
    }
 }
```

The following is the error which appears within the client web browser when called via
https://MyServer:8443

[image]

Since this code has worked fine previously, any recommendation as to what may have changed or what extra call needs to be made?

On a side note, the certificate being used is the same for another application so I would think that indicates it is not a certificate related issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this block of code ...

```
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory("/myDirecotry/mykeystore");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("myPassword");
```

... points to a old version of Jetty that is no longer supported. (Upgrade)

The current stable and supported versions of Jetty have Client/Server specific implementations of SslContextFactory now. (a change that was brought onto Jetty due to JVM behavior changes)

See [SecuredRedirectHandlerExample](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/jetty-10.0.x/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/SecuredRedirectHandlerExample.java) from the [embedded-jetty-cookbook](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/) project.

Next, check the certificates you are using in your keystore, you are likely using some technique with your certificate that is no longer supported by your JVM or your Browser. (eg: key length minimum requirements, crypto minimum requirements, etc)

See https://www.java.com/en/jre-jdk-cryptoroadmap.html for details about JVM crypto changes.

You can use the keytool to identify these kinds of certificate issues as well.

```bash
$ keytool -list -keystore src/main/resources/ssl/keystore -storepass storepwd
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

jetty, Nov 6, 2008, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 3D:75:8E:56:77:42:01:C7:D3:C3:E9:DF:8C:1B:21:03:19:70:78:A9:27:9E:F1:E4:78:B9:73:F5:F6:CA:EF:C2

Warning:
<jetty> uses the MD5withRSA signature algorithm which is considered a security risk and is disabled.
<jetty> uses a 1024-bit RSA key which is considered a security risk. This key size will be disabled in a future update.
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore src/main/resources/ssl/keystore -destkeystore src/main/resources/ssl/keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

First thing that this certificate is doing right is that it's `SHA-256` and not one of the other crypto techniques currently deprecated by the JVM.

But there are 2 warnings that should be addressed by creating a new certificate + keystore.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have been trying with the links provided above but it doesn't compile even after downloading the Jetty 11.014. Are you able to provide which JARs and versions are required? The AbstractHandler in the one example is giving me fits.

Comment: The AbstractHandler in the one example is giving me fits as the actual method to override is different than the example which makes me wonder if the correct version is being used. Also unable to find the code for SecuredRedirectHandlerExample.

Comment: Ignore the comment about the SecuredRedirectHandlerExample. That was a duh moment.

Comment: Finally got it built, but ended up with the same error. As mentioned previously, the certificate should be fine as it works with another application.